# Hop scp and sshfs using ssh tunnels

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-tunneling, sshfs

*Here's what I have*: A desktop and a laptop both behind a firewall, both of which can connect to an `ssh` capable server.

*Here's what I can do*: Create a tunnel from server to desktop by running this command on desktop

```
ssh userS@SERVER -R 2224:localhost:22 -fN -p 2222
```

Then I can `ssh` from laptop to server (pkey is enabled), then from there to desktop by running

```
ssh userS@SERVER -p 2222 ssh userD@localhost -p 2224
```

*Heres what I want to do*: Use `scp`, `sshfs`, and related connecting from laptop to desktop. I think I should somehow be able to do this using `ssh -L` from laptop, but havn't figured out the correct nomenclature. I tried (from laptop)

```
ssh userS@SERVER -p 2222 -fN -L 2225:localhost:2224
ssh userD@SERVER -p 2225
```

thinking that this would log me directly onto desktop, but it didn't work, hence my question here. This attempt denied the connection, as the ssh port on server is 2222. When I tried the above commands replacing 2225 with 2222 it tried to log me on to the server as `userD` just as it normally would without any tunnels. Am I on the right track with `ssh -L`? How do I make it work properly? If you feel I have left out any important information, please let me know and I will attempt to clarify. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does the command below work?

`% ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -p 2222 userS@SERVER /usr/bin/nc %h %p' userD@DESKTOP`

If so, you can bake the proxycommand into your `~/.ssh/config` to make `scp` and `sshfs` calls easier.